Getting error code 65 missing FirebaseCoreInternal.modulemap after update iOS 17.2
I've build a react-native application and today suddenly I get this error message on my terminal during run of the command react-native run-ios. The code work fine until the XCode force me to install iOS 17.2
This is my cocoapods
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

def pod_share
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreExtension', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseMessaging', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseSessions', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseInstallations', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleDataTransport', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'PromisesObjC', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'PromisesSwift', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'nanopb', :modular_headers => true

  pod 'WatermelonDB', :path => '../node_modules/@nozbe/watermelondb'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'simdjson', path: '../node_modules/@nozbe/simdjson'

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => false,
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )
end

target 'Proj' do
  pod_share

  target 'ProjTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end
end

target 'ProjUAT' do
  pod_share
end

post_install do |installer|
  react_native_post_install(
    installer,
    # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
    # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
    :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
  )
  __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      puts "===EXECUTE SET IOS DEPLOYMENT TARGET"
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '17.2'
    end
  end
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    puts "===EXECUTE RM UNARY BINARY FUNCTION"
    config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', '_LIBCPP_ENABLE_CXX17_REMOVED_UNARY_BINARY_FUNCTION']
    config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] << '_LIBCPP_ENABLE_CXX17_REMOVED_UNARY_BINARY_FUNCTION'
  end
end

This is work for me until the XCode required iOS 17.2
Here about my error
❌  fatal error: module map file '/Users/glabsmac/Documents/PROJECT/proj/proj-react-native/ios/build/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseCoreInternal/FirebaseCoreInternal.modulemap' not found

error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening Proj.xcworkspace.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

I've try to clean all dependency but still getting this error
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ && rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -f yarn.lock && rm -rf ios/build/ && rm -rf ios/Pods/ && rm -f ios/Podfile.lock && npm cache verify && yarn install && cd ios/ && npx react-native setup-ios-permissions && pod install --repo-update && cd ../

Please help

You can do some workarounds:
In ios folder



pod deintegrate
brew install cocoapods
pod install


Comment flipper functions in podfile;
 use_flipper!

 post_install do |installer|

 flipper_post_install(installer)

 end




Remove flipperInit in appDelegate.m
Run pod install inside ios folder
Clean project Run project again


try to run in xcode some time this


react-native run-ios

will not work

I not use flipper to my cocoapod anyway
